# angular 4 theming for background color changes

Tags: angular

I want to change the background color of the div on click of respective colored button in **angular 4**.

[image: Picture]

As shown in the above picture ,whenever I supposed to click on any color,the background should be change.

Comment: At least show what you have done so far

Comment: I haven't tried anything,I need idea to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a global variable called "color" and set it to default color. also make a function to toggle between colors.

```
public color = 'default';
changeColor(color: string) {
    this.color = color
}
```

In your css file define classes for each color

```
.default {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Now in your HTML code you can call that function passing color strings as input param. You can use this condition [ngClass]="color" to get the applied color in anywhere you want.

```
<div [ngClass]="color">
    <button (click)="changeColor('blue')">blue Button</button>
    <button (click)="changeColor('red')">red Button</button>
<div>
```